# ASP.NET MVC - NHibernate Many to Many - Where In Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with Fluent NHiberante, I get a relation many-to-many using those models:

```
# User model

public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

# Role model

public class Role
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}

# User map

class UsuarioMap : ClassMap<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
            .AsBag()
            .Inverse()
            .Table("role_user");
        Table("user");
    }
}


# Role map

public class PerfilMap : ClassMap<Role>
{
    public PerfilMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Users)
            .AsBag()
            .Cascade
                .All()
            .Table("role_user");            
        Table("role");
    }
}
```

And in the table where is linked the models with values will be displayed like that:

```
# Table role_user

Role_id  User_id
1        1
2        1
3        2
4        1
1        2
```

My doubt is, how can I create a NHibernate SQL that return only Users inside this table without repeat the Users.

I am trying to use "Where in", but until now whith now success:

```
         User user= null;
         List<Role> roles = null;

         var userList = NHibernateHttpModule.Session.QueryOver<User>(() => user)
             .JoinAlias(() => user.Roles, () => roles)
             .Where(Restrictions.In("User_id", Roles))
```

Comment: Do you want to return all Users who have at least one Role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var userList = NHibernateHttpModule.Session.Query<User>()
                                   .Where(x => x.Roles.Any())
                                   .ToList()
```

Note that I am using Linq to NHibernate instead of `QueryOver()`

Comment: Twoflower, there is no Query in NHiberante 3

Comment: There is, you just have to be `using NHibernate.Linq;`